# Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=31277, uid=10259 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

**Manifest File**

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="__PACKAGE__" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0">
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity" />
</application>
```

**device**

Galaxy s9 plus

**Steps to reproduce**

rm -rf platforms

tns run android --bundle

when the application launch it gives the following error

*issue**

```
System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=31277, uid=10259 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1967)
System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1913)
System.err:     at android.sec.clipboard.IClipboardService$Stub$Proxy.isEnabled(IClipboardService.java:757)
System.err:     at com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager.isEnabled(SemClipboardManager.java:1008)
System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.getSecClipboardEnabled(TextView.java:16134)
System.err:     at android.widget.EditText.onFocusChanged(EditText.java:250)
..........
```

Comment: What exactly you are doing in application launch? Does this even happen in fresh hello world template? Did you cross check with any other device?

Comment: i have only 2 screens one is login screen and another one is nativescipt-cardview screen
lets say after i build the application if my mobile was locked and if i give the pin number to start my phone it gives the above error
and if my phone was not locked it didn't give me any error and i am not able to navigate to second screen
i din't  try in other devices too
Thanks @Manoj

Comment: and i found that nativescript cardview also not working for android it is fine with ios it is not giving any error for android while navigating to second screen i am not able to navigate